# closure complete overview

Tags: javascript

Are only function call closure ,becoz in the code below object is also acting
 like a closure .

```
function makePerson(first, last) {
  return {
    first: first,
    last: last
  }
}

function personFullName(person) {
  return person.first + ' ' + person.last;
}

s = makePerson("Simon", "Willison");
personFullName(s); //output is: Willison, Simon
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer what is called closure exactly?

Comment: Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 2):

You're not using a closure anywhere in that code. You're merely returning an object that has some properties, and then using that object. The fact that the property values came from function parameters is immaterial.

You *are* relying on JavaScript's automatic memory management, but all JavaScript code relies on that. It doesn't mean you're using a closure.

Comment: Don't know why you were downvoted, but you're right, there's actually no closure involved.

Answer (score 1):

Since the values you pass in are in the function scope, yes they are part of the closure.

You are creating the object with those values at that point in time.

EDIT: in your example you're not really using a closure.

The following is an example of a closure:

```
function getCalcFunction(a, b){
    return function() {
         a + b;
    };
}
```

And you would use it like this;

```
var func = getCalcFunction(1, 3);
alert(func());    // alerts 4
```